# many configrations of a single machine with a single Vagrant file

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, salt-stack

I'm using Salt Stack to provision a Virtualbox vm using Vagrant and environment variables passed in from the command line to tell Vagrant which project to configure:

```
PROJECT='drupal-site' vagrant up
```

This value is then used to set a Salt minion's ID so that it configures itself correctly. I'm concerned that when a vm is provisioned and configured and then another project is specified from the cli, that the same vm instance will attempt to be configured again for a different project, when what I actually want is two vm instances. I don't want many Vagrant files if a single one will do.

I think this may be possible if I can control Vagrant's `:id` property but cannot figure out where this is set.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using Varant's multi-machine setup *BUT* using only a single machine:

```
PROJECT = ENV['PROJECT']
...
config.vm.define PROJECT do |project|
    project.vm.box = "precise64"
    project.vm.host_name = PROJECT + ".localhost"
...
```

Works a treat :D

Comment: wow - I don't remember asking this question and probably solved this problem the next day in just the manner you describe. That Vagrantfile is now parsing a yaml file of projects and prompting the user for a project to launch if one isn't specified and all kinds of other nice things. Code isn't public unfortunately.